# Paste Command removing input characters when spaces are present - Creating VariableGroups in Az pipelines

Tags: bash, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

**Summary:** Trying to create an automated script to create variable groups based on an input list in a text file. Script works so far except for the entries that have spaces in them. (This is not under my control, I know I would never name anything with spaces, but what can I do?) For whatever reason, the paste command seems to be weirding out on the entries with spaces in them, or at least I think it is paste that is doing it given the result of the echo commands you see above. Am I missing something obvious? On a related note, in a similar script, it seemed to remove "/" symbols unless I doubled up on them like "//". What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter your PAT"
read PAT
echo "Project Name"
read ProjName

for VarGroup in LaunchPointVariableGroups.txt; do
    vfile="$(basename -- $VarGroup)"
    paste $vfile | while read groupname; do
      echo "$groupname" "groupname"
      echo $vfile "vfile"
      echo $VarGroup "VarGroup"
      echo $ProjName "ProjName"

      AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT=$PAT az pipelines variable-group create --name $groupname --description $groupname --variables a=a --project "$ProjName"
    done
done
```

**Output is:**

> Examples from AI knowledge base: https://aka.ms/cli_ref Read more
> about the command in reference docs  groupnamerod DiscoveryServices"
> VariableGroups.txt vfile VariableGroups.txt VarGroup DevOps Poc
> ProjName  DEF Prod DiscoveryServices"Prod DiscoveryServices"
>
> Examples from AI knowledge base: https://aka.ms/cli_ref Read more
> about the command in reference docs  groupnamerod LMNOPConfig"
> VariableGroups.txt vfile VariableGroups.txt VarGroup DevOps Poc
> ProjName  DEF Prod LMNOPConfig"s: DEF Prod LMNOPConfig"

On lines like:
"ABC DEF Prod DiscoveryServices"
and "ABC DEF Prod LMNOPConfig"

Comment: please update the question with sample data from the file `LaunchPointVariableGroups.txt`; also update the question with a) the actual output from your script (eg, where's the output from the `echo` commands?) and 2) the expected output

Comment: I can't make any sense of the example output; please use code block format (as you did with the script), so its format is preserved. As for the script itself, why are you using `paste` at all? It's meant to combine multiple files, but you only have one here. Also, your quoting is backward; in shell, you don't need to quote fixed strings (unless they contain special characters), but you *should* double-quote variable references to avoid weird parsing of whitespace etc. So use `echo "$vfile vfile"` or `echo "$vfile" vfile` instead of `echo $vfile "vfile"`.

Comment: Sorry for the long time to respond guys. Work took me in a few other directions. @markp-fuso the contents of LaunchPointVariableGroups.txt is simply the names of various variable groups. It could be just about anything, just a list of groups, line by line like var-group1, var-group2, var-group3 and so on.

Comment: @GordonDavisson That was just the output response from the commands. Basically it was cutting off the first few words in string and erroring out on the latter. I discovered, by using shellCheck, that the errors were mostly due to not using -r flag with read commands which mangles backslashes and also not using double quotes which caused "globbing and splitting" Thank you both for your time checking out the question though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered, by using shellCheck, that the errors were mostly due to not using -r flag with read commands which mangles backslashes and also not using double quotes which caused "globbing and splitting"